# Navigate without touching the mouse

Tags: feature-request, support, user-interface, accessibility

I hate touching the mouse, is there a way to navigate through Stack Overflow questions without doing so?  I'm thinking something akin to Google's search results (not sure how long this has been a feature of theirs).  Once your at the google homepage, you can type your query then navigate the results using up/down arrow to select which result, then hit enter to go to that link.  Something like that would be cool, IMO.

Comment: Keyboard navigation is built into Opera and is [possible in Firefox](http://superuser.com/questions/50461/firefox-non-vimperator-way-to-do-mouseless-browsing).

Comment: I'm starting work on a userscript that will do this.  It'll be ready in 6 to 8 weeks.  The repo will be on [Github](http://github.com/rchern/StackExchangeScripts)

Answer (score 6):

I've done some work on the userscript I promised in a comment on this question.

> **[Install](https://github.com/rchern/StackExchangeScripts/raw/master/SEKeyboardShortcuts.user.js) | [Source](https://github.com/rchern/StackExchangeScripts/blob/master/SEKeyboardShortcuts.user.js)**

Please utilize the [Github Repository](http://github.com/rchern/StackExchangeScripts) [Issues 
page](http://github.com/rchern/StackExchangeScripts/issues) for reporting any feature requests or bugs.

It still needs a bit of polish (especially the help dialog), but it is functional, and I'd love to get some feedback.  You can access the list of commands via the help command:  `?`.

[image: shortcut screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

Till this feature is not implemented, you can try mouseless plugins, for example I can suggest [Vimium](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/dbepggeogbaibhgnhhndojpepiihcmeb) for Chrome. It will bind alternative key combination to each site link.

Answer (score 0):

> ... navigate the results using up/down arrow to select which result, then
>   hit enter to go to that link. Something like that would be cool, IMO.

My answer is not related to StackOverflow, but anyway.
Today I released my personal mouse emulator where, in most cases, the user can navigate up/down over text lines, links, icons, whatever, with a single key press.

If you're a Windows user, check it out https://github.com/ndandoulakis/SlickCursor

Sample image of *navigable* areas detected by the app

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can use [VimFx](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/vimfx/) for firefox. This is a awesome tool who doesn't like using mouse and who wants to make browsing fast.